# CSS position relative vs absolute

Tags: html, css

I have the following page (see code snippet below). I would like to position each of the items, so that when it is a full web page, the elements are i their desired positions, but as soon as it is viewed on narrow aspect ratio (e.g. mobile phone), then the items need to fold under each other.

I can get a full web page working, using `position: absolute;`. I can position the items where I want. But the problem is then on a mobile devise, the items overlap each other. So I figure I need to use `position: relative;`.

`position: relative;` allows the items to fold beneath each other on a narrow browser. However, I cannot seem to position the items where I want.

In the below example, I would like to position the items as follows:

```
                                    logo
                                    title
    text                                                    screen-print-one
    google apple web                                        screen-print-two


                                             Terms of Service  some@email.com
```

```css
body {
 font-family: "proxima-nova" ,"Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

/* logo */

.wz-logo {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
}

/* title */

.wz-title {
 font-size: 120%;
 color: #B2D137;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 20px 40px 30px;
}

/* text */
.text-description {
 padding-left: 10%;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 width: 500px;
}

/* screen-prints */

.screen-prints {
    position: relative;
 float: right;
 padding-right: 10%;
}

.screen-print1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  
}

.screen-print2 {
  position: relative;
   top: -430px;
   left: -120px;
 z-index: 1;
}

/* store */

.store-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

.store-container .apple, .img-container .google, .img-container .web {

 padding: 10px;
 padding-left: 20px;
}

.store-container .google {
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.store-container .apple {
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
}

.store-container .web {
 padding-top: 15px;
}

/* footer */

footer .terms, footer .contact {
 display:inline-block;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

footer .contact {
 padding-right: 40px !important;
}

footer a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 14px;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

footer {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body class="background-image">

 <div class="wz-logo">
  logo
 </div>

 <div class="wz-title">
  title
 </div>

 <div class="text-description">
  text
 </div>
  
   <div class="screen-prints">
  <div class="screen-print1">screen-print-one
  </div>
  <div class="screen-print2">screen-print-two
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="store-container">
  <div class="google">
   <a href="path to app on play store">google</a>
  </div>

  <div class="apple">
   <a href="path to app on apple store">apple</a>
  </div>

  <div class="web">
   <a href="path to website">web</a>
  </div>
 </div>

 <footer>

  <div class="terms">
   <a href="terms.html">Terms of Service</a>
  </div>

  <div class="contact">
   <a href="mailto:some@email.com" target="_top">some@email.com</a>
  </div>

 </footer>

</body>
```

If anyone can assist with how I can position the items, I would appreciate the help. (As you can see my main problem is trying to position the `screen-print-one` & `screen-print-two`).

Thanks

Comment: Too broad; this should not involve absolute or relative positioning (at least not on a large scale) - go read up on how common grid systems work.

Comment: I think you define the `position:relative` differently, check [here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

Comment: And as @CBroe said, you don't really need to use those to achieve that. Some floats would the trick

Comment: Thanks guys, I am no css expert, I think you have pointed me in the right direction. I need to looks at css grid systems I think.

Comment: Will a grid allow two items in one row positioned next to each other, to appear one beneath the other when the browsers aspect ratio is narrowed?  From what I can see, it doesn't allow this, so would not be suitable for what I am wanting. I stand to be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm there are a bunch of problems with your html logic. too many divs and not wrapped logically . but i made what i could with it

see below. or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wyx3o6uy/38/)

```css
.wz-logo,.wz-title {
 width:100%;
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
}

.left_text {
 float:left;width:50%;
}
.left_text .store-container  div{
 display:inline
}
.screen-prints {
 float:right;
 width:50%;
 text-align:right;
}
footer {
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 text-align:right
}
footer div {
 display:inline
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {

 
 .left_text,.screen-prints,footer {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
 }

}
```

```html
<body class="background-image">

 <div class="wz-logo">
  logo
 </div>

 <div class="wz-title">
  title
 </div>
<div class="left_text">


 <div class="text-description">
  text
 </div>
  <div class="store-container">
  <div class="google">
   <a href="path to app on play store">google</a>
  </div>

  <div class="apple">
   <a href="path to app on apple store">apple</a>
  </div>

  <div class="web">
   <a href="path to website">web</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div> 
   <div class="screen-prints">
  <div class="screen-print1">screen-print-one
  </div>
  <div class="screen-print2">screen-print-two
  </div>
 </div>



 <footer>

  <div class="terms">
   <a href="terms.html">Terms of Service</a>
  </div>

  <div class="contact">
   <a href="mailto:some@email.com" target="_top">some@email.com</a>
  </div>

 </footer>

</body>
```

i suggest you use bootstrap for responsiveness . it's much easier to use

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I see you use `float:left;width:50%;`, which I think may help.

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I need.